# Paypal Smart Button Integration - Is there a way i can add a discount coupon/SKU to the order.create function?

Tags: paypal

I have a Paypal Smart Button integration with my eCommerce site. The entire setup is: User clicks on the Paypal button -> makes a payment -> IPN call to my backend -> saves data to database. This flow is working fine for me.

I now want to be able to pass a discount SKU to Paypal so i can capture it in my database with the IPN call. Right now, only the discount amount ie being sent to Paypal depending on the coupon code used.

Here's my current code:

````
                    purchase_units: [{
                        description: "Zing Energy Patches",
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: currencyCode,
                            value: (basePrice + shippingPrice + tax - creditPrice).toFixed(2),
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: currencyCode,
                                    value: basePrice
                                },
                                shipping: {
                                    currency_code: currencyCode,
                                    value: shippingPrice
                                },
                                tax_total: {
                                    currency_code: currencyCode,
                                    value: tax
                                },
                                discount:{
                                    currency_code: currencyCode,
                                    value: creditPrice
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        items: productsArray
                    }]
                });```

I tried adding the discount as an item with negative value, but Paypal rejected the request stating that negative values are not allowed.
````

Comment: help us help you by setting up a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)